# Find the real values of $x$ that satisfy the equation $7[x]+23\{x\}=191$

Tags: linear-algebra, ceiling-and-floor-functions, fractional-part

For any real number $x$, $[x]$ denotes the largest integer less than or equal to $x$ (i.e. floor function) and $ \{x\}=x-[x]$ .Then, the number of real solutions of the equation $$7[x]+23\{x\}=191$$ are.

**My Attempt:**

I used $ \{x\}=x-[x]$

This gives us,

$$23x-16[x]=191$$

as,$16[x]$ is an integer, $23x$ also must be an integer.

How to proceed next?

Comment: Why should $23x$ is an integer imply that $x$ is an integre?

Comment: and multiplying a real number with a prime produces an integer only if the number was alreday an integer?

Comment: So, for instance $7/23$ is an integer? @prog_SAHIL

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown, ah, how must I proceed this then?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen, got it. Any ideas on how to tackle this?

Comment: Let $y=23x$. Now $y$ is an integer. Moreover, $y\equiv191\pmod{16}$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown, I am not familiar with mods.

Comment: @prog_SAHIL Perhaps this question will spur you into learning modular arithmetic.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77089/discussion-between-prog-sahil-and-lord-shark-the-unknown).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

- $23x-16[x]=191$ is a nice idea, but $7x+16\{x\}=191$ may be more useful
- Using $0 \le \{x\} \lt 1$, can you put an upper bound on $7x$? A lower bound?
- If you knew $[x]$, could you find $\{x\}$ and so $x$?
- How many possible values of $[x]$ are there? Do they all give a value of $x$ which works?

Comment: Solved it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the solution here for future references.

$$7[x]+23\{x\}=191$$

We know that, $0\leq23{\{x\}}\lt23$,

i.e. as long as $$168\lt7[x]\leq191$$

We can always find a $23{x}$ **(one and only one)** in $[[x],[x]+1)$ such that,

$$7[x]+23\{x\}=191$$

This gives us $[x]=25,26,27$

as $[x]=24$ gives $7[x]=168$, this will just lie on the boundary.

So, **3 solutions**.

Answer (score 0):

Here my attempt...

$\mathrm{7}\left[{x}\right]+\mathrm{23}\left\{{x}\right\}=\mathrm{191} \\ $
$\left[{x}\right]+\frac{\mathrm{23}\left\{{x}\right\}−\mathrm{2}}{\mathrm{7}}=\mathrm{27} \\ $
$\left\{{x}\right\}\in\left\{\frac{\mathrm{2}}{\mathrm{23}},\frac{\mathrm{9}}{\mathrm{23}},\frac{\mathrm{16}}{\mathrm{23}}\right\} \\ $
${x}=\mathrm{27}−\frac{\mathrm{23}\left\{{x}\right\}−\mathrm{2}}{\mathrm{7}}+\left\{{x}\right\} \\ $
${x}\in\left\{\mathrm{27}\frac{\mathrm{2}}{\mathrm{23}},\mathrm{26}\frac{\mathrm{9}}{\mathrm{23}},\mathrm{25}\frac{\mathrm{16}}{\mathrm{23}}\right\} \\ $

Hope this acceptable...

Answer (score 0):

$$\mathrm{7}\left[{x}\right]+\mathrm{23}\left\{{x}\right\}=\mathrm{191} \\ $$
$$\left[{x}\right]=\frac{\mathrm{191}−\mathrm{23}\left\{{x}\right\}}{\mathrm{7}} \\ $$
$$\left[{x}\right]=\frac{\mathrm{191}−\mathrm{23}\left[\mathrm{0};\mathrm{1}\right)}{\mathrm{7}} \\ $$
$$\left[{x}\right]=\left[\mathrm{25};\mathrm{27}\right] \\ $$
$$\mathrm{7}\left[{x}\right]+\mathrm{23}\left({x}−\left[{x}\right]\right)=\mathrm{191} \\ $$
$${x}=\frac{\mathrm{191}+\mathrm{16}\left[{x}\right]}{\mathrm{23}} \\ $$
$${x}=\left\{\frac{\mathrm{591}}{\mathrm{23}},\frac{\mathrm{607}}{\mathrm{23}},\frac{\mathrm{623}}{\mathrm{23}}\right\} \\ $$